# Multithreading on list not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a list of about 1000 items that I need to search via Facebook. I make it multithreaded so I can speed up the process of searching things. Unfortunately it seems like some threads are just taking a combination item and not even processing it.

The issue with that is, when they get a new combination I remove it from my `List<string>` just so that it doesn't get searched multiple times when it doesn't need to be.

It's not like I'm using lots and lots of threads, I'm using 3.

```
class BrowserHandler
{
    public static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public BrowserHandler()
    {
        StartBrowser();
        StartBrowser();
    }

    private void StartBrowser()
    {
        var combination = Program.GetServer().GetNextCombination();
        Logger.Debug(combination);
        runBrowserThread(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=" + combination));
    }

    private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() => {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate(url);
            Application.Run();
        });

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;

        if (br.Url == e.Url)
        {
            if (br.DocumentText.Contains("_52eh _5bcu"))
            {
                var links = br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {
                    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "_52eh _5bcu")
                    {
                        Logger.Warn("Found owner for [" + e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1] + "] " + link.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Warn("Finished checking [" + e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1] + "] and found no owner.");
            }

            Application.ExitThread();
            StartBrowser();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  12:56:24 - 07999999991
  12:56:24 - 07999999891
  12:56:24 - 07999999791
  12:56:27 - Found owner for [07999999991] Kaydie-anne Hairdressa Reid
  12:56:27 - Found owner for [07999999891] Yuli Berk
  12:56:28 - 07999999691
  12:56:28 - 07999999591
  12:56:29 - Finished checking [07999999791] and found no owner.
  12:56:29 - Finished checking [07999999691] and found no owner.
  12:56:29 - 07999999491
  12:56:29 - 07999999391
  12:56:29 - Finished checking [07999999591] and found no owner.
  12:56:30 - 07999999291
  12:56:30 - Finished checking [07999999491] and found no owner.
  12:56:31 - 07999999191
  12:56:31 - Finished checking [07999999391] and found no owner.
  12:56:31 - 07999999091
  12:56:32 - Finished checking [07999999291] and found no owner.
  12:56:32 - Finished checking [07999999191] and found no owner.
  12:56:32 - 07999998991
  12:56:32 - 07999998891
  12:56:33 - Finished checking [07999999091] and found no owner.
  12:56:33 - 07999998791
  12:56:34 - Found owner for [07999998991] Suzanne McMaster
  12:56:34 - 07999998691
  12:56:35 - Finished checking [07999998891] and found no owner.
  12:56:35 - 07999998591
  12:56:35 - Finished checking [07999998791] and found no owner.
  12:56:36 - 07999998491
```

As you can see, 16 get taken from the list, only 13 finish being checked.

Comment: That seems a very high overhead approach. Why not use an HTML parser (eg. AngleSharp) rather than spinning up many browser instances)?

Comment: How can one even dare to use a single `WebBrowser` control from a non-UI thread? Left alone multiple instances.

Comment: I need a browser because Facebook forces you to be logged in to search certain querys.

Comment: Can I ask why its being downvoted? It's a very good question that I am asking.

Comment: Why are you screen scraping? Have you made sure there is no Facebook API for what you need or does it not meet your requirements?

Comment: The API limits requests to a very small amount.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to set the apartment state to STA?

Answer (score 2):

There could be some results which did not pass the test in your foreach iteration, manage them somehow via a boolean flag like this..

```
class BrowserHandler
{
    public static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public BrowserHandler()
    {
        StartBrowser();
        StartBrowser();
    }

    private void StartBrowser()
    {
        var combination = Program.GetServer().GetNextCombination();
        Logger.Debug(combination);
        runBrowserThread(new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=" + combination));
    }

    private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() => {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate(url);
            Application.Run();
        });

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;

        if (br.Url == e.Url)
        {
            if (br.DocumentText.Contains("_52eh _5bcu"))
            {
                var links = br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                bool AnyFound=false; 
                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {
                    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "_52eh _5bcu")
                    {
                        Logger.Warn("Found owner for [" + e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1] + "] " + link.InnerText);
AnyFound= true;
                    }
                }

if(!AnyFound) {
Logger.Warn("Finished checking [" + e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1] + "] and found no owner.");
}
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Warn("Finished checking [" + e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1] + "] and found no owner.");
            }

            Application.ExitThread();
            StartBrowser();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already checked this, it still doesn't show the 3 missing items.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add `else` in your foreach, may be there will be your missing 3 items:

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "_52eh _5bcu")
    {
        Logger.Warn("Found owner for [" + e.Url.ToString().Split('=')[1] + "] " + link.InnerText);
    }
    else 
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I already checked this, it still doesn't show the 3 missing items.

Comment: May be your app is finished before the last three threads completed? and thats why you are missing these 3 log messages?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "app is finished" ? Finished as in closed?

Comment: yes, I mean that may be the application is closed before these last 3 threads completed.

Comment: How can that be possible? I'm waiting, if the application was closed I wouldn't even know if it had missed any in the first place.

Comment: You are parsing the document using the DocumentCompleted event. Facebook makes heavy use of AJAX, so they might be streaming some results to improve performance.

Comment: To follow up on @VDN comment, try adding a 10s delay before you process the document & see if you get the missing data.

Comment: This doesn't work, and I knew it wouldn't before I even tried it. It's an issue with the thread not executing, if the code reached that stage it would log it either way.